# what're Pipeline and TxPipeline redis functions in gloang

Tags: go, redis

I want to perform an atomic transaction in redis using golang. How to do that ? What is the difference b/w Pileline and TxPieline and how to solve the problem using them. 
I have visited the following link:
https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/redis.v5#example-Client-TxPipeline

But explanation is not elaborate.

Comment: Problem solved. Didn't know to use pipe.<redisFunctions> . Got it now. Thanks for your time anyhow.

Comment: I still confused what is difference between pipeline, pipelined, txpipeline and txpipelined. Doc is so minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Code from one of the examples from the library on how to use transaction.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
)

var redisdb *redis.Client

func main() {
    var incr *redis.IntCmd
    _, err := redisdb.Pipelined(func(pipe redis.Pipeliner) error {
        incr = pipe.Incr("pipelined_counter")
        pipe.Expire("pipelined_counter", time.Hour)
        return nil
    })
    fmt.Println(incr.Val(), err)
}
```